# Android Studio Gradle Update

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm attempting to update my `gradle` version within Android Studio. I am attempting to use version 2.10, but am running into issues.

Within my `gradle-wrappers.properties` I have

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Inside my `build.gradle` file for my project I have

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Within my Android Studio preferences, I do have `Use default gradle wrapper` selected. The errors I'm getting

```
4:04:01 PM Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.10.
           Searched in the following locations:
           file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.pom
           file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.jar
           https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.pom
           https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.jar
           Required by:
           :MyApp:unspecified
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

I can see it's trying to find two files: `gradle-2.10.pom` and `gradle-2.10.jar`. Am I supposed to install those files manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the gradle wrapper you don't need to change the version of Android Plugin for Gradle.

The last version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle` is 2.0.0. Change your `build.gradle` like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse the **gradle plugin for android** with the **gradle version**.

With this line you are declaring the gradle plugin. Use

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

The gradle version is defined in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. Use:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```